# UITableViewDelegate crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have some view controllers, that have `UITableView` inside. They all have base class - `BaseTableViewController`.

`BaseTableViewController` implements some `UITableViewDelegate` logic, so it also have some stub delegate methods, especially for row selecting:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}
```

As you can see it's empty method, so subclasses doesn't call it.
However crash reports from Crashlytics say me that this method is crashing. I can't reproduce it by myself:

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x100e88a18 _TFs16_assertionFailedFTVs12StaticStringSSS_Su5flagsVs6UInt32_Os5Never + 164
1  MyApp                          0x10028ae14 BaseTableViewController.tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt : IndexPath) -> () (BaseTableViewController.swift)
2  UIKit                          0x190f2bd30 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
3  UIKit                          0x190f2bcb0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
4  UIKit                          0x190f16128 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 452
5  UIKit                          0x190f2b59c -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 584
6  UIKit                          0x1914b6628 _UIGestureEnvironmentSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 4484
7  UIKit                          0x1914b26c0 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1164
8  UIKit                          0x1914b21e0 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 408
9  UIKit                          0x1914b149c -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 268
10 UIKit                          0x190f2630c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 2960
11 UIKit                          0x190ef6da0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
12 UIKit                          0x1916e075c __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2736
13 UIKit                          0x1916da130 __handleEventQueue + 784
14 CoreFoundation                 0x18afeeb5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
15 CoreFoundation                 0x18afee4a4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
16 CoreFoundation                 0x18afec0a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
17 CoreFoundation                 0x18af1a2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
18 GraphicsServices               0x18c9ce198 GSEventRunModal + 180
19 UIKit                          0x190f617fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
20 UIKit                          0x190f5c534 UIApplicationMain + 208
21 MyApp                          0x100128c30 main (main.m:14)
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x189efd5b8 (Missing)
```

As you can see it's very strange report. Firstly, this method shouldn't be called since child view controller never call `super.tableView(didSelectRowAt)`. Secondly it doesn't look like normal `tableView(didSelectRowAt)` call - there aren't calls from table view, only direct call for delegate method. Thirdly, this method is empty, and there is nothing to crash.

I assume that there is some memory issues since Crashlytics report also say:

```
# RAM Free: 3.3%
# Disk Free: 3.3%
```

However I don't know is it true or not.

Could you please advice me how can I debug and solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

PS According to reports it's not one time crash, it occurs very often.

Comment: when does this happen?

Comment: @John I don't know. This trace is all I have. I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Crashlytics should indicate a code line or something, otherwise show the did select code

Comment: @John `didSelect` method is empty.

Comment: @frozen_lion delete the `didSelect` method and again run your project and check what happens.

Comment: then why implement it ? if it is empty you also don't need to set `delegate` for your `UITableView`

Comment: @John as I said base class implements some delegate logic, but not didSelect. I left empty method in base class to mark that it's implemented in childs. Ok, I'll try to remove it.

Comment: Hey, I don't know why it is crashing. At the same time your understanding is not proper about the inheritance. According to inheritance if you override the method then according to the instance the runtime will make sure to call the overridden methods. If you didn't override a method in here `didSelect`, so it will call the super class method.